# In Kotlin, how do I integrate a Kovenant promise with Elasticsearch async responses?

Tags: elasticsearch, kotlin, kovenant

I use Kovenant in my Kotlin application, and I'm calling Elasticsearch which has its own async API.  I would rather use promises but the best I can come up with is something like:

```kotlin
task {      
    esClient.prepareSearch("index123")
            .setQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery())
            .execute().actionGet()
} then { 
    ...
} success {
    ...
} fail {
    ...
}
```

Which makes an Kovenant async task thread, then Elasticsearch uses a thread from its pool, and then `actionGet()` synchronously blocks Elasticsearch to get back a result.  It seems silly to spawn new threads while blocking others.  Is there an approach to integrate the thread dispatching more closely?

**Note:** *this question is intentionally written and answered by the author ([Self-Answered Questions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)), so that solutions for interesting problems are shared in SO.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Kovenant [`Deferred` class](http://kovenant.komponents.nl/api/core_usage/#deferred) to create a promise without dispatching via an async `task` as you did in your sample.  The model is basically:

1. create a deferred instance
2. hook up to the async handlers and resolve or reject the deferred based on async callbacks
3. return the `deferred.promise` to the caller

In code, this would look like:

```
fun doSearch(): Promise<SearchResponse, Throwable> {
    val deferred = deferred<Response, Throwable>()
    esClient.prepareSearch("index")
        .setQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery())
        .execute(object: ActionListener<T> {
                   override fun onResponse(response: T) {
                       deferred.resolve(response)
                   }

                   override fun onFailure(e: Throwable) {
                       deferred.reject(e)
                   })
    return deferred.promise
}
```

A re-usable way to do this is to first create an adapter that can just adapt Elasticsearch's desire for an `ActionListener` to work generically work with a promise:

```
fun <T: Any> promiseResult(deferred: Deferred<T, Exception>): ActionListener<T> {
   return object: ActionListener<T> {
       override fun onResponse(response: T) {
           deferred.resolve(response)
       }

       override fun onFailure(e: Throwable) {
           deferred.reject(wrapThrowable(e))
       }
   }
}

class WrappedThrowableException(cause: Throwable): Exception(cause.message, cause)
fun wrapThrowable(rawEx: Throwable): Exception = if (rawEx is Exception) rawEx else WrappedThrowableException(rawEx)
```

Note:  the `wrapThrowable()` method is there to change a `Throwable` into an `Exception` because current versions (`3.3.0`) of Kovenant have some methods that expect the rejection type of the promise to descend from `Exception` (*for example [`bind()`](http://kovenant.komponents.nl/api/functional_usage/#bind)*) and you can stay with `Throwable` if you use [`unwrap()`](http://kovenant.komponents.nl/api/core_usage/#unwrap) instead for nested promises.

Now use this adapter function to generically extend Elasticsearch `ActionRequestBuilder` which is pretty much the only thing you ever will call `execute()` on; creating a new `promise()` extension function:

```
fun <Request: ActionRequest<*>, Response: ActionResponse, RequestBuilder: ActionRequestBuilder<*, *, *, *>, Client: ElasticsearchClient<*>>
        ActionRequestBuilder<Request, Response, RequestBuilder, Client>.promise(): Promise<Response, Exception> {
    val deferred = deferred<Response, Exception>()
    this.execute(promiseResult(deferred))
    return deferred.promise
}
```

Now you can call `promise()` instead of `execute()`:

```
esClient.prepareSearch("index")
            .setQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery())
            .promise()
```

And start chaining your promises...

```
esClient.admin().indices().prepareCreate("index1").setSettings("...").promise()
        .bind {
            esClient.admin().cluster().prepareHealth()
                    .setWaitForGreenStatus()
                    .promise()
        } bind {
            esClient.prepareIndex("index1", "type1")
                    .setSource(...)
                    .promise()
        } bind {
            esClient.prepareSearch("index1")
                    .setQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery())
                    .promise()
        } then { searchResults ->
            // ... use searchResults
        }.success {
            // ...
        }.fail {
            // ...
        }
}
```

You should be familiar with [`bind()`](http://kovenant.komponents.nl/api/functional_usage/#bind) and [`unwrap()`](http://kovenant.komponents.nl/api/core_usage/#unwrap) when you have nested promises you want to chain without nesting deeper.  You can use `unwrap().then` in place of `bind` in the above cases if you did not want to include [`kovenant-functional`](http://kovenant.komponents.nl/api/functional_usage/).

Every call you have in Elasticsearch will be able to use `promise()` instead of `execute()` due to the consistent nature of all request objects in the Elasticsearch client.